# power supply specification

Tags: pi-2, pi-3b+

are there any public requirements (which I have not found) specifing power supply ramps / gradients

e.g. is there a spec like from 0 to 5V in 5ms or faster

also when turning of, is there any requirement how fast to go from 5 to 0V or can we have a ramp down e.g. when discharging a buffer capacitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Arm processor requires that `reset` is kept low until the power is stable. I suspect that the Pis honor that requirement.

For power-down, the ARM says:

> 6.3.2 Power-Off Sequence

> The power supplies can be powered-off in any order as long as LVCMOS supplies operated at 3.3V
> (DVDD3318_A, DVDD3318_B, or DVDD3318_C) never exceed static 1.8V supplies by more than 2 volts.
> There is no specific required voltage ramp down rate for any of the supplies (except as required to meet
> the above mentioned voltage condition).

So the main processor should not be a problem. You may want to investigate for the specific memory card that you use.

Note that the diagrams for the Pi are available at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/README.md. You can see the additional power circuitry there (f.e. the processor runs of 3.3V, not 5V)

Comment: Well I expect the PI hardware to handle that. In industrial devices I work with, we have hard requirements with slow ramps and such. The intend of my question is more like if the external 5V supply has special constraints which e.g. a external supply need to comply with, or if the Pi is hardend enougth to cope with e.g. slow rise and fall times

Answer (score 1):

There are no such documented requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The only requirements on 5V supply is that it is within 5% and can supply sufficient current.

The SOC **DOES NOT** use 5V but a number of lower voltages. These have sequencing requirements but this is handled by the PMIC.